# How to create a 3-way relationship between NHibernate entities?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, entity, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following NHibernate entity classes:

```
public class ProductPrice
{
    private long _id;
    private long _price; //Let's not get side-tracked by the type
    private Currency _currency;
}

//Just showing for completeness; the link beween ProductPrice and Currency
//is working correctly
public class Currency
{
    private long _id;
    private String _threeLetterCode; //INR, USD, GBP, OMR etc.
    private String _displayName;
    private IList<ProductPrice> _productPrices = new List<ProductPrice>();
}

public class Item
{
    private long _id;
    private String _name;
    private IList<ProductPrice> _prices = new List<ProductPrice>();
}

public class Customer
{
    private long _id;
    private String _name;
    private IList<ProductPrice> _prices = new List<ProductPrice>();

}
```

I want to create a separate mapping table that links the tuple `(Customer, Item,
ProductPrice)` as we want to be able to offer the same item at different prices
to different customers.  The `Currency` to `ProductPrice` is a simple
one-to-many relationship.

I am at a loss how to map this in the .hbm.xml files.

So far I have (doing just a partial mapping):

```
<class name="Item" table="Items">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <bag name="Prices" table="PriceList" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="false">
    <key column="ItemID" />
    <many-to-many class="ProductPrice" column="PriceID" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

and

```
<class name="ProductPrice" table="ProductPrices" lazy="true">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Price" />
  <many-to-one name="Currency" class="Currency" column="CurrencyID" />
</class>
```

This only maps `(Item, ProductPrice)`, but even this doesn't cause an entry to
be saved in the `PriceList` table when I create a new `ProductPrice`, add it to
a `Currency`, add it to a new `Item`, then save `Item` and `Currency`.

So the questions I have are:

1. What am I missing?

   1. How do I make sure that an entry is made in the `PriceList` table when I
      create a `ProductPrice`, add it to an `Item` and save the `Item`?
2. How do I extend this two-way `(Item, ProductPrice)` mapping to a three-way
   `(Customer, Item, ProductPrice)` mapping?
3. How do I do it so that I can have multiple identical `(Customer, Item,
   ProductPrice)` rows in the `PriceList` table (`ProductPrice` has validity
   dates (not shown here) so as be able to offer short-lived special pricing)?

Version 2:

I have the following NHibernate entity classes:

```
public class ProductPrice
{
    private long _id;
    private long _price; //Let's not get side-tracked by the type
    private Currency _currency;
    private IList<Item> _items = new List<Item>();
}

//Just showing for completeness; the link beween ProductPrice and Currency
//is working correctly
public class Currency
{
    private long _id;
    private String _threeLetterCode; //INR, USD, GBP, OMR etc.
    private String _displayName;
    private IList<ProductPrice> _productPrices = new List<ProductPrice>();
}

public class Item
{
    private long _id;
    private String _name;
    private IList<ProductPrice> _prices = new List<ProductPrice>();
}

public class Customer
{
    private long _id;
    private String _name;
    private IList<ProductPrice> _prices = new List<ProductPrice>();

}
```

I want to create a separate mapping table that links the tuple `(Customer, Item,
ProductPrice)` as we want to be able to offer the same item at different prices
to different customers.  The `Currency` to `ProductPrice` is a simple
one-to-many relationship.

I am at a loss how to map this in the .hbm.xml files.

So far I have (doing just a partial mapping):

```
<class name="Item" table="Items">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <bag name="Prices" table="PriceList" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="false">
    <key column="ItemID" />
    <many-to-many class="ProductPrice" column="PriceID" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

and

```
<class name="ProductPrice" table="ProductPrices" lazy="true">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Price" />
  <many-to-one name="Currency" class="Currency" column="CurrencyID" />
  <bag name="Items" table="PriceList" >
    <key column="PriceID" />
    <many-to-many class="Item" column="ItemID" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

This only maps `(Item, ProductPrice)`, but even this doesn't cause an entry to
be saved in the `PriceList` table when I create a new `ProductPrice`, add it to
a `Currency`, add it to a new `Item`, then save `Item` and `Currency`.

So the questions I have are:

1. What am I missing?

   1. How do I make sure that an entry is made in the `PriceList` table when I
      create a `ProductPrice`, add it to an `Item` and save the `Item`?
2. How do I extend this two-way `(Item, ProductPrice)` mapping to a three-way
   `(Customer, Item, ProductPrice)` mapping?
3. How do I do it so that I can have multiple identical `(Customer, Item,
   ProductPrice)` rows in the `PriceList` table (`ProductPrice` has validity
   dates (not shown here) so as be able to offer short-lived special pricing)?

### Update 1

Added a list of `Item` to `ProductPrice` and updated `ProductPrice.hbm.xml`.

### Update 2

An unshophisticated way of solving this would be to define an entity `PriceLink`
like this:

```
public class PriceLink
{
    protected virtual long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Cust { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductPrice ProdPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and map it like so:

```
<class name="PriceLink">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="Cust" class="Customer" column="CustomerID" />
  <many-to-one name="Item" class="Item" column="ItemID" />
  <many-to-one name="ProdPrice" class="ProductPrice" column="ProductPriceID" />
</class>
```

However, with this solution I lose (I think) all of the power of NHibernate's
ability to retrieve an entire object graph.  Is this ghetto solution worth it?

### Update 3

This is how I was saving the entities (before I tried `PriceLink`) in a unit
test (yes, I realize this is hack-y code and I am not using transactions):

```
Currency curr = new Currency { DisplayName = "XYZ Currency", ThreeLetterCode = "XYZ" };
ProductPrice prodPrice = new ProductPrice { SalePrice = 10000, ValidFrom = DateTimeOffset.MinValue, ValidUpto = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue };
Item item = new Item { Name = "Item 1"};
//PriceLink pl = new PriceLink();
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    prodPrice.Currency = curr;
    curr.ProductPrices.Add(prodPrice);
    //pl.Item = item;
    //pl.ProdPrice = prodPrice;
    prodPrice.Items.Add(item);
    item.Prices.Add(prodPrice);
    session.Save(curr);
    session.Save(item);
    //session.Save(pl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider around what items you would like to access yourdata store. In other words, instead of tying all items together, think about the root aggregates.

In the described model you might want to consider just having a currency class without having a reference from currency towards the productprices.

That way the model will become somewhat simpler although the user stories might have driven you this way first, not sure?

Having said that, I would not want nhibernate be so powerfull to retrieve all the entire object graph, but rather choose multiple of those graphs. Like a product with its prices, and another user story you might want to go for the currency as the aggregate root.